# Put Multiple Functions into one Switch-Case Statement - Python

Tags: python, switch-statement

My script currently looks for four different scenarios by using three different functions. Doing it this way sometimes causes errors because I don't know which scenario will occur first or if it will occur at all. I think that putting these scenarios into one "switch-case" statement would fix this problem.

Here are the three functions:

```
def bypass_consent(driver):
    try:
        consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit' and @value='I agree']")))
        consent.submit()
    except:
        try:
            consent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                'button.tftvyvi6t678')
            consent.click()
        except:
            pass

def bypass_agree(driver):
    frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.ID, "iframe")))
    driver._switch_to.frame(frame)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.ID, "introAgreeButton"))).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()

def bypass_signin(driver):
    sleep(1)
    nothanks = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "style-scope.fu-button-renderer.style-text.size-small")))
    nothanks.click()
    sleep(randint(1, 5))
    bypass_agree(driver)
```

Here's what I tried (unsuccesssfully):

```
def scenario(i):
    switcher={
            0:consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                        (By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit' and @value='I agree']")))
                        consent.submit(),
            1:consent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                        'button.tftvyvi6t678')
                        consent.click(),
            2:frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                      (By.ID, "iframe")))
                      driver._switch_to.frame(frame)
                      WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                      (By.ID, "introAgreeButton"))).click()
                      driver.switch_to.default_content(),
            3:sleep(1)
              nothanks = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                         (By.CLASS_NAME, "style-scope.fu-button-renderer.style-text.size- 
                         small")))
                         nothanks.click()
                         sleep(randint(1, 5))
                         bypass_agree(driver)
            
         }
     return switcher.get(i)
```

Comment: How did it become unsuccessful? Unexpected output (what was intended)? Errors?

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` pointing to the equal sign in `0:consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(`

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary of code can be fixed with this:

```
def case_0():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit' and @value='I agree']")))
                    consent.submit()

switcher={
    0: case_0

    # ...
}

switcher[case]()
```

or you could use an exec() (probably don't)

```
exec('WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit' and @value='I agree']"))); consent.submit()')
```

I know that something like a switch statement is going to be implemented in 3.10 though...

Comment: How does that address the different scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a switch function like this:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

It is used in a for statement, using a C-like pattern:

```
for case in switch(i):
    if case(0):
        consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit' and @value='I agree']")))
        consent.submit()
        break

    if case(1):
        consent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                    'button.tftvyvi6t678')
        consent.click()
        break

    if case(2):
        frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                  (By.ID, "iframe")))
        driver._switch_to.frame(frame)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                  (By.ID, "introAgreeButton"))).click()
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        break

    if case(3):
        sleep(1)
        nothanks = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                     (By.CLASS_NAME, "style-scope.fu-button-renderer.style-text.size- 
                     small")))
        nothanks.click()
        sleep(randint(1, 5))
        bypass_agree(driver)
        break
```